# Use uuid as primary and/or as surrogate key?

Tags: database-design, uuid

We are required to add UUID's to most of our objects and database tables.

Would you use the UUID as surrogate key, or rather as natural key in addition to a sequence generated surrogate key, i.e. use a private surrogate key and in addition add a column/attribute to hold the UUID?

I see that it is often used directly as surrogate / primary key. Somehow I don't like the idea.

One might view a UUID as a natural key, since it should be a unique identifier with a global meaning just like any other natural key, independent of a particular implementation of a system, i.e. if you would ever move your data to another system, the UUID must stay the same, whereas surrogate keys by definition have no real and lasting meaning.

Maybe I should have clarified more: suppose we have an Account table. Traditionally there would be some internal surrogate key and a natural key consisting of the account number (as printed on account statements etc.).

Whereas the UUID is not as "readable" as the account number, I would view a UUID more like the natural key because it could serve the same purpose as the account number: to refer to a particular account in a unique and unchanging manner. The (traditional) surrogate key never appears outside of the system, since it is completely private and could be changed at any time, no external references must ever exist to it.

In that sense a UUID is not a typical surrogate key (?).

Comment: Natural keys are formed from creating keys based on the data. UUIDs are surrogate keys, just globally unique surrogates.

Comment: @andrey: the reason behind not liking the idea is that foreign keys get very large.

Comment: @plmuon are you having size issues with our database? If not then don't do premature optimization.

Comment: @andrey: once you choose a particular type of surrogate key, it is hard to change. I do know that we will have several million references to all of our "accounts", i.e. large foreign keys will blow up the DB size quite a bit, require more I/O, read over more physical file blocks etc. The optimization is not necessarily premature.

Comment: @Andrey, determining right domain for your data is *not* premature optimization. Field size influences: all I/O, index size, data storage requirements, backups; for any scan retrievals of data this directly translates to performance, for lookups not directly, but still influences.

Comment: What is reason you are adding UUIDs? This may dictate how they should be treated. Yes UUIDs are slower in joins but for some purposes are necessary. In other cases they are used as an additional field but the joins are done with integer surrogate keys for performance.

Comment: @Andrey, only a fool doesn't try to optimize a database in the design phase. Databases designed by devlopers who think all optimization is premature are a bithc to fix when they have 100,000,00 records and a design that was a bad choice from day one. This is NOT a premature optimization as this choice will affect virtually all queries and performance.

Comment: @HLGEM did you read first part of my comment? If you have less then a 1M rows guid or int will not affect performance much.

Comment: @Andrey, "will not affect performance *much*." - great reasoning ;)

Comment: @Unreason I have seen a lot of different problems with DB performance but never root cause was GUID as PK. I am pretty sure that no other commentor also seen it. Everyone are just saying general phrases about sizes, IO etc. but I doubt that GUID as PK caused real problems to someone. Prove that I am wrong :)

Comment: @Andrey, the logic goes like this: Increasing the size of PK by factor x will increase the size of the index by factor x. This will increase the system resources required by x for index scans (very common operation). This will reduce the number of possible concurrent users by some percentage of x. That will bring down scalability and availability of the system. This is a non issue *only* on a system that will not be stressed and such system is already over-dimensioned which is *not* true for serious DB systems. These implications are not imaginary, they are as real as they come.

Comment: @Unreason I repeat again, this is *correct theorization*. But in practice I never seen when GUID as PK made serious problems. Have you?

Comment: @Andrey, I can not explain this further. At this point it should be clear to you that these implications are not theory, but reality.  Maybe you are puzzled by the fact that in practice you don't see the end effect because database do scale and once the system is finished you will bench mark it and spend more money on hardware and make it work. And yes I have seen that - systems slower due to wrong data domains. I have also seen systems limited with too rigid data domains causing additional development costs, too. Determining correct domains is quite important.

Comment: @Unreason I am talking not about general "wrong data domains" but specifically about GUIDs as PK/FK. Have you seen problems caused by them?

Comment: @Andrey, yes, I have seen performance improvement switching from GUIDs to natural keys. And Andrey, we are talking about right and wrong data domains. Keep in mind that the issue is not only limited to performance, but also to proper modelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing things up a bit.

1) There are two definitions of surrogate keys

> Surrogate (1)
>
> This definition is based on that given by Hall, Owlett and Todd (1976).
>   Here a surrogate represents an entity
>   in the outside world. The surrogate is
>   internally generated by the system but
>   is nevertheless visible to the user or
>   application.
>
> Surrogate (2)
>
> This definition is based on that given by Wieringa and De Jonge (1991).
>   Here a surrogate represents an object
>   in the database itself. The surrogate
>   is internally generated by the system
>   and is invisible to the user or
>   application.
>
> The surrogate (1) definition defines
>   its usage in the data model rather
>   than the storage model and is used in
>   this article. See Date (1998).

(from wiki's entry on [surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) keys; read the article with a bit of scepticism - for example quote '*Surrogate keys are less expensive to join (fewer columns to compare) than compound keys*' might seem reasonable on the surface, but natural compound keys will create indexes that are naturally ordered and segregated, allowing for very efficient scans when browsing or analyzing data, also due to the same logic joins that return resultsets containing several rows can actually perform much better)

Anyway, when considering surrogate keys from the perspective of the data model, you should *not* consider what you call a 'traditional' definition.

2) Your logic for considering UUIDs natural keys is very slippery

quoting from your question:

> I would view a UUID more like the
>   natural key because it could serve the
>   same purpose as the account number: to
>   refer to a particular account in a
>   unique and unchanging manner.

This is not a defining nor distinguishing characteristic of natural keys vs surrogate keys. Natural keys have following properties (from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key)):

> A natural key is a candidate key that
>   has a logical relationship to the
>   attributes within that row. A natural
>   key is sometimes called a domain key.
>
> The main advantage of a natural key
>   over a surrogate key, which has no
>   such logical relationship, is that it
>   already exists; there is no need to
>   add a new, artificial column to the
>   schema. Using a natural key (when one
>   can be identified) also simplifies
>   data quality: It ensures that there
>   can only be one row for a key; this
>   "one version of the truth" can be
>   verified, because the natural key is
>   based on a real-world observation.

Normally there is no logical relationship between UUID and the attributes of the same row. However, if UUIDs are assigned by an external system and if you already have a requirement to store them as an attribute then you have that logic (similarly like you could consider a serial number or social security number a natural key).

Only in this sense UUID might stop being surogate key and yet still you might have (and probably will have) stronger and richer logic for another candidate key for the same row.